# Encountered error “ReferenceError: $ is not defined” using react-materialize

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, materialize

I'm relatively new to React/Webpack and I want to apply Materialize CSS, but I am getting error about not recognizing jQuery in my code. I do not know where to begin.

I have a simple React Component as so:

**src/component/header**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Navbar, NavItem } from 'react-materialize';
export default class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Navbar brand='logo' right>
        <NavItem href='get-started.html'>Getting started</NavItem>
        <NavItem href='components.html'>Components</NavItem>
      </Navbar>
    );
  }
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "redux-simple-starter",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Simple starter package for Redux with React and Babel support",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": "git@github.com:StephenGrider/ReduxSimpleStarter.git",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js",
    "test": "mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --require ./test/test_helper.js --recursive ./test",
    "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.2.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.1.18",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.1.18",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "chai-jquery": "^2.0.0",
    "jquery": "^2.2.1",
    "jsdom": "^8.1.0",
    "mocha": "^2.4.5",
    "node-sass": "^3.8.0",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.3.1",
    "webpack": "^1.13.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.1.18",
    "css-loader": "^0.24.0",
    "jquery": "^2.2.4",
    "lodash": "^3.10.1",
    "materialize-css": "^0.97.7",
    "node-sass": "^3.8.0",
    "react": "^15.3.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.30.3",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.1 ",
    "react-materialize": "^0.15.2",
    "react-redux": "^4.0.0",
    "react-router": "^2.0.1",
    "redux": "^3.0.4",
    "sass-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "shortid": "^2.2.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
var path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './src/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel',
      query: {
        presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-1']
      }
    },{
      test: /\.s?css$/,
      loaders: ['style','css','sass'],
      include: path.join(__dirname, 'src')
    }]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
    alias: {
    'jquery': path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery'),
    }
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './'
  }
};
```

Error message:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/css/materialize.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="fcc">
      <div class="container"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="/bundle.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, you're loading jQuery **after** the body, which you shouldn't, it should go **inside** the head or body, and jQuery should go before any other scripts that uses it, like materialize.

Comment: Yep, can't believe I totally missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try including `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>` before `<script src="/bundle.js"></script>`.

JQuery is used inside bundle.js but it's not defined yet.

Comment: Oops! I totally missed that obvious thing. That did the trick :)